# Java streams getting a List from map of maps

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following variable declaration

```
Map<EventType<? extends Event>, Map<EventSource, List<EventHandler<? super Event>>>> eventHandlers;
```

Using java streams I would like to filter this map first on eventType then filter on eventSource ending up with a List.

How do I go about doing this using java streams, I have tried several different approaches but without success. the implementation I have thus far is

```
List <Object> something = eventHandlers.entrySet().stream().filter(entry
                        -> entry.getKey() == event.eventType || event.eventType.isSubType(entry.getKey())
                ).map(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I just end with a `List<Map<EventSource, List<EventHandler<? super Event>>>>`

How do I achieve this, any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: you can  `flatMap` to entrySet to get a stream of entries of your sub maps, then filter again, then map to keep only the value, then flatmap again to flatten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, something like this (written without compiler, so there might be some errors) should work:

```
List<EventHandler<? super Event>> output = eventHandlers
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey() == event.eventType || event.eventType.isSubType(entry.getKey()))
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .map(Map::entrySet)
    .flatMap(Set::stream)
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey() == event.eventSource) // ? Modify the filter on event source according to your needs
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that you can shorten a bit, using lambdas instead of function references:

```
List<EventHandler<? super Event>> output = eventHandlers
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey() == event.eventType || event.eventType.isSubType(entry.getKey()))
    .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().entrySet().stream())
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey() == event.eventSource) // ? Modify the filter on event source according to your needs
    .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Many thanks, just what I was looking for.